# How to put a border around a group of datatables

Tags: visualforce, html

I have 3 `<apex:dataTable>` in my component. I'd like to put a border around all 3. I'm not getting it however. Any suggestions?

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="myCont">
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!custId}" description="The SF ID" id="custId" name="custIDFromEmail" type="String"/>
    <br/>

    <apex:dataTable bgcolor="EEEEEE" border="below" cellspacing="5%" columnsWidth="30%" value="{!innerClassFieldList}" var="c" width="70%">
        <apex:facet name="header">Information</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!c.label}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Field Name</apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!c.value}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Value</apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <apex:dataTable border="below" cellspacing="5%" columnsWidth="30%" rendered="{!updateArrayLabelSize}" value="{!updateArrLabels}" var="c" width="70%">
        <apex:facet name="header">Additions / Updates</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!$ObjectType.Customization__c.fields[c].label}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Field Name</apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!myCust[c]}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Value</apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <apex:dataTable bgcolor="EEEEEE" border="below" cellspacing="5%" columnsWidth="30%" rendered="{!deleteArrayLabelSize}" value="{!delArrLabels}" var="c" width="70%">
        <apex:facet name="header">Remove</apex:facet>
        <apex:column value="{!$ObjectType.Customization__c.fields[c].label}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enclose all three of your tables inside of one pair of `div` tags, and apply a border to the `div` using CSS. You may need to add a [clearFix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) class to your div in order for the border to surround all three, but I'm not 100% sure that will be necessary.

Comment: Clear fix isn't necessary unless you have odd positioning (float). Usually page blocks are not floating.

Comment: Makes sense! I wasn't sure what Salesforce's underlying CSS was for data tables so I figured I'd mention it, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The [apex:dataTable `border` attribute](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) is a number of pixels not a string so replace "below" with a numeric value such as "1".

To gain access to the more flexible [CSS styling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp), use the `style` and `styleClass` attributes.